# How to login to a website with python and mechanize

Tags: python, cookies, authentication, mechanize, webautomation

i'm trying to log in to the website http://www.magickartenmarkt.de and do some analyzing in the member-area (https://www.magickartenmarkt.de/?mainPage=showWants). I saw other examples for this, but i don't get why my approaches didn't work. I identified the right forms for the first approach, but it's not clear if it worked.
In the second approach the returing webpage shows me that i don't have access to the member area.

I would by glad for any help.

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
import urllib
import requests
import mechanize
from mechanize._opener import urlopen
from mechanize._form import ParseResponse

USERNAME = 'Test'
PASSWORD = 'bla123'
URL      = "http://www.magickartenmarkt.de"

# first approach
request = mechanize.Request(URL)
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
# I don't want to close?!
#response.close()

# Username and Password are stored in this form
form = forms[1]

form["username"] = USERNAME
form["userPassword"] = PASSWORD

#proof entering data has worked
user = form["username"]  # a string, NOT a Control instance
print user
pw = form["userPassword"]  # a string, NOT a Control instance
print pw
#is this the page where I will redirected after login?
print urlopen(form.click()).read () 

#second approach
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : USERNAME, 'userPassword': PASSWORD})

#login
response_web = opener.open(URL, login_data)

#did it work? for me not....
resp = opener.open('https://www.magickartenmarkt.de/?mainPage=showWants')
print resp.read()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why not use a browser instance to facilitate navigation?  Mechanize also has the ability to select particular forms (e.g. nr = 0 will select the first form on the page)

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(YOUR URL)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['username'] = USERNAME
browser.form['password'] = PASSWORD
browser.submit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It works like a charm. Do I need to worry about cookies with this implementation? Also found 
`browser.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)`
this. Does it mean that the browser-(object?) will refresh the webpages every second?

Comment: The browser will save the cookies in it's own session (they are lost once the script terminates or you are no longer using that particular instance).  HOWEVER, if you want these cookies to be available for future sessions (e.g. on future calls to a script for as long as the cookies aren't expired), you'll have to use cookielib, http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html

Comment: I believe it's `browser = mechanize.Browser()`

Comment: Good catch.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Web automation ? Definitely "WEBBOT"

**`webbot`** works even for webpages with dynamically changing id and classnames and has more methods and features than selenium.

> Here's a snippet :)

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com') 
web.click('Sign in')
web.type('mymail@gmail.com' , into='Email')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('mypassword' , into='Password' , id='passwordFieldId') # specific selection
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span') # you are logged in ^_^
```