# How can I login this page and read it?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, authentication, mechanize

I know there are alot of question about this matter but I try most of them.
my goal is to get the article from  [this page](http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/ahmet-hakan_131/baskanlik-diktatorluk-getirir-diyenleri-girtlaklamak-istiyorum_28116073) and use this in gae.

If I try to log in, it redirects to a [long url](https://hurpass.com/iframe/login?appkey=52da7ef64037f9497f0acb091390051062215&secret=52da7f0c4037f9497f0acb0b1390051084754&domain=sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr&callback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fsosyal.hurriyet.com.tr%2FAccount%2FAutoLogin%3FreturnUrl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fsosyal.hurriyet.com.tr%2Fyazar%2Fahmet-hakan_131%2Fbaskanlik-diktatorluk-getirir-diyenleri-girtlaklamak-istiyorum_28116073%3F__hrp__&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fsosyal.hurriyet.com.tr&user_page=http%3A%2F%2Fsosyal.hurriyet.com.tr%2FAccount%2FAutoLogin%3FreturnUrl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fsosyal.hurriyet.com.tr%2Fyazar%2Fahmet-hakan_131%2Fbaskanlik-diktatorluk-getirir-diyenleri-girtlaklamak-istiyorum_28116073%3F__hrp__&is_mobile=0&session_timeout=0&is_vative=0&email=) ,after I log in there it redirects back to the article.

first I try urllib2 which is mentioned in here [how to login to a website with python and mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598145/how-to-login-to-a-website-with-python-and-mechanize)  and it didnt work.

then I took SelectLoginForm and login functions from https://github.com/cdhigh/KindleEar/blob/master/books/base.py it didnt work neither.

selenium wouldnt work because I gonna use it in gae. I guess gae cant support selenium

I started looking into mechanize module. my current code is :

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
import cookielib 
import urllib2 
import mechanize 
b=mechanize.Browser()
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize.HTTPRefreshProcessor(),max_time=1)
b.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]

b.open('https://hurpass.com/iframe/login?appkey=52da7ef64037f9497f0acb091390051062215&secret=52da7f0c4037f9497f0acb0b1390051084754&domain=sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr&callback_url=http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/Account/AutoLogin?returnUrl=http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/ahmet-hakan_131/baskanlik-diktatorluk-getirir-diyenleri-girtlaklamak-istiyorum_28116073&referer=http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr&user_page=http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/Account/AutoLogin?returnUrl=http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/ahmet-hakan_131/baskanlik-diktatorluk-getirir-diyenleri-girtlaklamak-istiyorum_28116073&is_mobile=0&session_timeout=0&is_vative=0&email=')


b.select_form(name='frm_login')


b["email"]="tasklak@hotmail.com"
b["password"]="123456"

b.submit(type="submit")

url='http://sosyal.hurriyet.com.tr/yazar/ahmet-hakan_131/baskanlik-diktatorluk-getirir-diyenleri-girtlaklamak-istiyorum_28116073'

last_response = b.response() 
http_header_dict = last_response.info().dict
html_string_list = last_response.readlines()
html_data = "".join(html_string_list)
page = br.open(url)
print page.read().decode("UTF-8")

ha=open("test.html",'w')
ha.write(html_data)
ha.close
```

again I cant get this working but if I open the html it created, it redirects to logged article page. may it be mechanize redirection problem or is it impossible to login this page?

edit after mihail's answer:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

user = 'tasklak@hotmail.com'
password = '123456'
xor_password = ''.join(chr(12 ^ ord(c)) for c in password)

auth_url = 'http://auth.hurriyet.com.tr/api/loginuser/{}/?{}'.format(user, xor_password)
url='http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/anasayfa/'

sessionidd=urllib2.urlopen(auth_url).read().split(',')[1].split('\"')[3]

print sessionidd

opener.open(url+';ASPSESSIONID='+sessionidd)
print cj
```

edit 2:

```
sessionidd=urllib2.urlopen(auth_url).read().split(',')[1].split('\"')[3]
print sessionidd
opener.open(url)
k=0
for a in cj:
    if k<2:
        a.value=sessionidd
        k+=1
print cj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should know that if there isn't a publicly available API to do all this without scraping then it's very likely that what you are doing is not welcomed by the website owners, against their terms of service  and could even be illegal and punishable by law depending on where you live.

Unless `mechanize` can interpret javascript code (which I doubt it does although I might be wrong) it's not going to be very helpful, although, skimming through the links you provided with Chrome's DevTools it looks like you could implement what you want with a few pure `urlib2` requests.

For example, when you login for the first time, you'll see a GET request  to `http://auth.hurriyet.com.tr/api/loginuser/tasklak@hotmail.com/?%3D%3E%3F89%3A` URL which includes your username and encoded password and returns some session IDs. The reason `mechanize` wouldn't work is because the password is encoded via a javascript code that's not being interpreted when you are submitting the form in your code.

Going into the source code of the login form you'll see that when the "Submit" button is clicked a `loginUser()` function is called which when you'll find you'll see that the password is being xor'ed with the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < password.length; ++i) {
    encoded_password += String.fromCharCode(12 ^ password.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

which you would have to rewrite in python, so to recieve the initial session IDs you'd have something like:

```
import urllib2

user = 'tasklak@hotmail.com'
password = '123456'
xor_password = ''.join(chr(12 ^ ord(c)) for c in password)

auth_url = 'http://auth.hurriyet.com.tr/api/loginuser/{}/?{}'.format(user, xor_password)

print(urllib2.urlopen(auth_url).read())
```

It looks like you're then going to need to validate the session IDs you received and retrieve session cookies which you then can use to get full articles but I will leave that to you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. when I try something like this i get "HTTP Error 404: Not Found" error. could you please check my edit?

Comment: Why is your next step doing this:  `opener.open(url+';ASPSESSIONID='+sessionidd)`? try opening in your browser the result (i.e. http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/anasayfa/;ASPSESSIONID=54d60911362173180424d779 ) and you will also get a 404 so that's kind of expected. You simply need to take a look at the `loginUser()` trying to understand what it does (the next step is some kind of validation as I remember) and try to convert it to python code.

Comment: after I press login at mainpage (hurriyet.com/anasayfa) i saw this link on the developer panel. http://uyelik.hurriyet.com.tr/oauth.aspx?xid1=3e643180-75a4-49a5-8231-5813c351d595&tv1=5&ssosid=54d63bdc36217302a07b3fc6&ssosv=635589301724435365-a670428b-f61b-4cd2-8c13-52f1b7be1cb9&ssoid=54d4333dc04f7b292cb0068054d4333dc04f7b292cb00681&ssoucp=http%253a%252f%252fwww.hurriyet.com.tr%252fanasayfa%252f    is it smth related to this ? if it is ,we know ssoid from your print. and I guess  ssosv is session value. how do we get xid1?

Comment: I cant open new question sadly. I exract this url from the source code of my first code on the thread was created. http://i.imgur.com/12cEdsV.jpg    if we fill in the blanks with the values that your code printed would we get somewhere?