# Login to website with Python where link is always different

Tags: python, authentication, web

I've already tried the code on a different website so I know it works, however: it doesnt work on my schools website (and I think I already know why)

This link is always different. Is there any way to log in to that website?

(I'm using Requests btw)

Comment: do you mind sharing the code you wrote down so far ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to modifying the URL to contain your username and password, if you are why not try emulating a browser instead. [Mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598145/how-to-login-to-a-website-with-python-and-mechanize)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this website is apparently blocking screen scrapers.
So act like a browser:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://intranet.hhs.nl/nl/Paginas/home.aspx',
    headers=headers)
```

Redirection is done by `Requests`.
You're probably going to need [cookie handling](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies), too